Can I calculate the percentage of a value and summarize this information over every sampling-date?



Date
Tree
Compound
Compound_mg
%mg




13.1
a
C21
5



13.1
b
C21
4
x


13.1
c
C21
9



20.2
a
C21
6



20.2
b
C21
5
x


20.2
c
C21
10



13.1
a
C23
6



13.1
b
C23
6
x


13.1
c
C23
10



20.2
a
C23
5



20.2
b
C23
4
x


20.2
c
C23
9




This is how my data looks, except for the the last column, which I wish to get. I have sampled three trees (N=3) and have extracted compounds, several from each tree, but on different dates to see how the proportions change over time.
I would like to know, how many %mg is C21 of all the compounds, at each time-point. So what proportion does C21 make up of all compounds on 13.1 (averaged by 3 trees), and how much it makes up on 20.1 aso. Then the same for C23.
Example dataset:
Df <- data.frame(
  rating = 1:12,
  Date = c('13.1','13.1','13.1','20.2','20.2','20.2','13.1','13.1','13.1','20.2','20.2','20.2'),
  Tree = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'),
  Compound = c("C21","C21","C21","C21","C21","C21","C23","C23","C23","C23","C23","C23"),
  Compound_mg = c(5, 4, 9, 6, 5, 10, 6, 6, 10, 5, 4, 9)
)

I tried this...
Df2 <- Df %>%
group_by(Compound) %>%
mutate(perc = Compound(mg) / sum(Compound(mg))

But I don't know how to average the 3 trees (a,b, and c), or how to incorporate Date

In base R you could do the following:
(prop <- proportions(xtabs(Compound_mg~Date+Compound,Df),1))

      Compound
Date         C21       C23
  13.1 0.4500000 0.5500000
  20.2 0.5384615 0.4615385

If you want a dataframe:
as.data.frame(tab,responseName = 'perc')

  Date Compound      perc
1 13.1      C21 0.4500000
2 20.2      C21 0.5384615
3 13.1      C23 0.5500000
4 20.2      C23 0.4615385



library(dplyr)

Df |>
  group_by(Date, Compound) |>
  mutate(sum_c = sum(Compound_mg)) |>
  ungroup() |>
  group_by(Date) |>
  mutate(sum_d = sum(Compound_mg), perc = sum_c/sum_d) |>
  ungroup() |>
  dplyr::summarise(.by = c(Date, Compound, perc)) |>
  arrange(Date, perc)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   Date  Compound  perc
#>   <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 13.1  C21      0.45 
#> 2 13.1  C23      0.55 
#> 3 20.2  C23      0.462
#> 4 20.2  C21      0.538

Created on 2024-11-14 with reprex v2.1.1.9000

For a compact solution using dplyr the order of aggregation is important. There are many ways to do it, but this sequence will cut down on the total number of steps needed:

Aggregate the daily totals for each compound using group_by() |> summarize()
Compute the proportion within each day without aggregating further using group_by() |> mutate()

In the second step the group_by allows you to compute a separate total across all compounds for each date, but using the resulting total in the mutate that follows (instead of summarize) will yield a data set with the same number of rows.
Df |>
    group_by(Date, Compound) |>
    summarize(Compound_mg = sum(Compound_mg)) |>
    group_by(Date) |>
    mutate(perc = Compound_mg / sum(Compound_mg)) |>
    ungroup()

# A tibble: 4 × 4
  Date  Compound Compound_mg  perc
  <chr> <chr>          <dbl> <dbl>
1 13.1  C21               18 0.45 
2 13.1  C23               22 0.55 
3 20.2  C21               21 0.538
4 20.2  C23               18 0.462


library(dplyr)
count(Df, Date, Compound, wt = Compound_mg) |>
  mutate(perc = n / sum(n), .by = Date)

  Date Compound  n      perc
1 13.1      C21 18 0.4500000
2 13.1      C23 22 0.5500000
3 20.2      C21 21 0.5384615
4 20.2      C23 18 0.4615385

Or we could join the data to that summarized version of itself:
left_join(DF, count(Df, Date, Compound, wt = Compound_mg) |>
                mutate(perc = n / sum(n), .by = Date))

   rating Date Tree Compound Compound_mg  n      perc
1       1 13.1    a      C21           5 18 0.4500000
2       2 13.1    b      C21           4 18 0.4500000
3       3 13.1    c      C21           9 18 0.4500000
4       4 20.2    a      C21           6 21 0.5384615
5       5 20.2    b      C21           5 21 0.5384615
6       6 20.2    c      C21          10 21 0.5384615
7       7 13.1    a      C23           6 22 0.5500000
8       8 13.1    b      C23           6 22 0.5500000
9       9 13.1    c      C23          10 22 0.5500000
10     10 20.2    a      C23           5 18 0.4615385
11     11 20.2    b      C23           4 18 0.4615385
12     12 20.2    c      C23           9 18 0.4615385

